# Confusion with the Spread Operator

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using the React Context API for the first time.  I have an object with several "top level" properties and easily figured out how to update them.  But now I'm trying to add & edit the contents of an object array.  I have add working one way but am confused why it won't work with the spread operator the way I expected.

Here's a simplified version of my 'corporateCustomer' Context object:

```
    companyName: string
    notes: string
    users[]:
      id: integer
      email: string
      firstName: string
      lastName: string
```

This code seems to work:

```
  const addNewUser = (idx) => {
    const newUser = {id: idx, email: '', firstName: '', lastName: ''};
    corporateCustomer.users = [...corporateCustomer.users, newUser];

    setCorporateCustomer(corporateCustomer => {
      return {
        ...corporateCustomer,
        users: corporateCustomer.users
      }
    });
  };
```

But this fails:

```
  const addNewUser = (idx) => {
    const newUser = {id: idx, email: '', firstName: '', lastName: ''};

    setCorporateCustomer(corporateCustomer => {
      return {
        ...corporateCustomer,
        users: [...corporateCustomer.users, newUser];
      }
    });
  };
```

This is very confusing because the only change was a simple refactor but when I console.log `corporateCustomer.users` in the 2nd case, there are 0 whereas in the first case there is 1.

Why is my second set of code failing?

Comment: In the 2nd code block newUser would be undefined, because its a callback function and when that is getting executed it has no idea what newUser is and hence it fails

Comment: In the first case, you seem to be using `corporateCustomer` outside the callback function. Are both of those the same variable?

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier `newUser` would be defined by property of closures

Comment: Your code is working fine - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jehmfs

Comment: What is that `setCorporateCustomer` function? Have you put a debugger breakpoint in the callback to confirm it is getting called when you expect it?

Comment: This is so weird.  ` ravibagul91` is correct.  The refactored version of my code works fine ... this morning! :-)  I probably should be posting such "bugs" late at night when my brain is more than a little tired.  Thank you all for your responses.